# Jquery datepicker: validate date mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: asp.net, jquery, datepicker

I have a textbox and a datepicker next to it and I am using asp.net and the user can enter the date as well select the date from datepicker.

How would you validate if the date is entered correct?

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            $('#<%=StartDate.ClientID%>').datepicker({ showOn: 'button', 
                    buttonImage: '../images/Calendar.png', 
                    buttonImageOnly: true, onSelect: function () { }, 
                    onClose: function () { $(this).focus(); } 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: That depends on what your definition of a correct date is?

Comment: eg 30/30/2008 is a NOT a valid date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET, you can use an ASP.NET Compare Validator [[ASP.NET Date Validator](http://blogs.mgtechgroup.com/markc/archive/2007/06/07/ASP.NET-Date-Validator.aspx)].

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CompareValidator ID="cv" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="tb" ErrorMessage="* Please enter a valid date!" Text="*" 
Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

**** Update**

I took the javascript that was executed by the Compare Validator above and wrapped a custom jQuery Validation method around it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.validator.addMethod("truedate", function (value, element, params) {
            function GetFullYear(year, params) {
                var twoDigitCutoffYear = params.cutoffyear % 100;
                var cutoffYearCentury = params.cutoffyear - twoDigitCutoffYear;
                return ((year > twoDigitCutoffYear) ? (cutoffYearCentury - 100 + year) : (cutoffYearCentury + year));
            }

            var yearFirstExp = new RegExp("^\\s*((\\d{4})|(\\d{2}))([-/]|\\. ?)(\\d{1,2})\\4(\\d{1,2})\\.?\\s*$");
            try {
                m = value.match(yearFirstExp);
                var day, month, year;
                if (m != null && (m[2].length == 4 || params.dateorder == "ymd")) {
                    day = m[6];
                    month = m[5];
                    year = (m[2].length == 4) ? m[2] : GetFullYear(parseInt(m[3], 10));
                }
                else {
                    if (params.dateorder == "ymd") {
                        return null;
                    }
                    var yearLastExp = new RegExp("^\\s*(\\d{1,2})([-/]|\\. ?)(\\d{1,2})(?:\\s|\\2)((\\d{4})|(\\d{2}))(?:\\s\u0433\\.)?\\s*$");
                    m = value.match(yearLastExp);
                    if (m == null) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    if (params.dateorder == "mdy") {
                        day = m[3];
                        month = m[1];
                    }
                    else {
                        day = m[1];
                        month = m[3];
                    }
                    year = (m[5].length == 4) ? m[5] : GetFullYear(parseInt(m[6], 10));
                }
                month -= 1;
                var date = new Date(year, month, day);
                if (year < 100) {
                    date.setFullYear(year);
                }
                return (typeof (date) == "object" && year == date.getFullYear() && month == date.getMonth() && day == date.getDate()) ? date.valueOf() : null;
            }
            catch (err) {
                return null;
            }
        }, "Please enter an actual date.");

        $("#form1").validate();

        $("#one").rules('add',
        {
            truedate: {
                cutoffyear: '2029',
                dateorder: 'mdy'
            }
        });
    });

</script>

<input id="one" />
```

Comment: i know i have option to use asp.net control but i wanted to try using jquery validation.

Comment: i took the javascript produced by the compare validator and wrapped a custom method around it

Comment: you could also use 'remote' and on the server try to convert it to a date which will also only work if it's a valid date

Comment: @Doc, getting this error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$.validator' is null or not an object

Comment: do you have references to both jquery and jquery validation ? (http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.5.5/jquery.validate.min.js)

Comment: oops i was missing the validation js.

Comment: @doc, how can i make seperate function (validaiton of date) so  i can use on my other pages. - thanks.

Comment: just put the '$.validator.addMethod("truedate"...' code in a separate .js file and reference it on our other pages

Answer (score 33):

I use this handler for validate input:

```
   onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        try {
            $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateText);
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        };
```

Hope, it'll be useful for somebody

Comment: Such a perfect answer with such little fanfare!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using a mix of Katrin & Doc Holiday's approach, using the datepicker control's parseDate utility method in a custom validator I've called isDate.

Just change the format argument in parseDate to the appropriate value (reference: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate).

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.validator.addMethod('isDate', function(value, element)
        {
            var isDate = false;
            try
            {
                $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
                isDate = true;
            }
            catch (e)
            {

            }
            return isDate;
        });

        $("#form1").validate();

        $("#dateToValidate").rules("add", { isDate: true, messages: {isDate: "Date to Validate is invalid."} });
    });
```

It's probably not best practice for the validator to be referencing a UI control but what the heck. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jquery, you could check out http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ which has great flexibility for validations..

Comment: i am using bassistance.de for my form validation but i dont find any example for date validation, if you find please redirect me.

Comment: it has a date validation, but it only checks the format of the string, so "30/30/2008" would be a valid date

Comment: @Doc: so there is no real way to check date? or am i left with only option to use asp.net validatin controls?