# jquery datepicker : Validate current input value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I've been using the Datepicker plugin from jQuery UI. I want to be able to validate if the input textbox it is attached to currently has a valid date or not.

For example:

If someone decides to type in `02/30/2010` I'd like to be able to somehow ask the plugin if that current input value is a valid date (which it is not in this case).

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem today. I'm truly shocked by how half-baked and incomplete everything in jQuery UI is every time I try to use it. What a crock. :(

Answer (score 8):

You can solve your problem by making text box read only and set date format as you like. So User is not able to type anything in text box, user only select correct date format(which you set) from date picker. Please see the below example.

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30" readonly="readonly"/></p>    
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat",'yy-mm-dd');
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is terribly usability. Some users would rather type their dates than faff around with a calendar!

Answer (score 7):

It's very easy

```
let value = $(this).val();
let format = $(this).datepicker('option', 'dateFormat');
let valueIsValid = false;
try {
    $.datepicker.parseDate(format, value);
    valueIsValid = true;
}
catch (e) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

Although this question is almost two years old, I have recently dealt with a similar solution and found that the [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) library is the best approach.  For example, suppose you have a textbox that has a jQueryUI datepicker attached to it.  When focus is lost on the textbox, you can use Globalize to validate the entered date.  In this case the textbox is blanked if the date is invalid or put in a standard format if the date is valid:

```
$('#myDateTextBox').blur(function () {
    var parsedDate = Globalize.parseDate($(this).val());
    if (parsedDate == null) {
        $(this).val('');
    } 
    else {
        $(this).val(Globalize.format(parsedDate, 'd'));
    }
```

The `Globalize` library allows you to specify a culture (using the language of the request ideally) so the user can enter a date in the format for their culture.

Comment: I don't think the dateFormats for various cultures even match up between Globalize and jQueryUi DatePicker.  In globalize.culture.fr-CA.js I see a date format like this:  yyyy-MM-dd.  In datepicker-fr-CA.js I see a date format like this:  yy-mm-dd.  I don't think the date format tokens are the same between the two.  How are uppercase 'M's interpreted versus lowercase 'm's?

Comment: @ClearCloud8 I wrote a utility to generate the jQueryUI datepicker localization files so they matched the formats used in Globalize.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense.  Good idea.  :)  It still drives me crazy why date format tokens would be interpreted inconsistently.  I know momentJs expects capital MMs whereas jqueryUI Datepicker expects lowercase mm's.  Would be nice to have a consistent approach.... or at least some resource that compared the tokens across different software and showed equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the **dateFormat** and **constrainInput** options of the datepicker.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: I don't use constrainInput because I want people to be able to use a slash or dash as a seperator. However, I don't see how using that would allow me to know if someone enters a day that doesn't exist. Such as Feb 30th.

Comment: constraintInput doesn't fix this at all. It stops me typing text in, doesn't stop me typing "5".

Comment: @DannyTuppeny - might be worth noting, while what you mentioned is correct, constraintInput does not prevent cut & pasting text into the input

Answer (score 0):

I added a "truedate" method to the validator.  I'd love to credit whoever's code this is, but I don't remember where I found it.

```
$.validator.addMethod("truedate", function (value) {
        function GetFullYear(year) {
            var twoDigitCutoffYear = 10 % 100;
            var cutoffYearCentury = 10 - twoDigitCutoffYear;
            return ((year > twoDigitCutoffYear) ? (cutoffYearCentury - 100 + year) : (cutoffYearCentury + year));
        }

    if (value == null || value == '')
        return true;
    var yearFirstExp = new RegExp("^\\s*((\\d{4})|(\\d{2}))([-/]|\\. ?)(\\d{1,2})\\4(\\d{1,2})\\.?\\s*$");
    try {
        m = value.match(yearFirstExp);
        var day, month, year;
        if (m != null && (m[2].length == 4)) {
            day = m[6];
            month = m[5];
            year = (m[2].length == 4) ? m[2] : GetFullYear(parseInt(m[3]));
        }
        else {
            var yearLastExp = new RegExp("^\\s*(\\d{1,2})([-/]|\\. ?)(\\d{1,2})(?:\\s|\\2)((\\d{4})|(\\d{2}))(?:\\s\u0433\\.)?\\s*$");
            m = value.match(yearLastExp);
            if (m == null) {
                return null;
            }
            day = m[3];
            month = m[1];
            year = (m[5].length == 4) ? m[5] : GetFullYear(parseInt(m[6]));
        }
        month -= 1;
        var date = new Date(year, month, day);
        if (year < 100) {
            date.setFullYear(year);
        }
        return (typeof (date) == "object" && year == date.getFullYear() && month == date.getMonth() && day == date.getDate()) ? date.valueOf() : null;
    }
    catch (err) {
        return null;
    }
}, "Please enter an actual date.");

$('form').validate({
                rules: {
                    insurance_GL: "truedate",
                },
                messages: {
                    insurance_GL: "Insurance GL date is not valid",
                }
});
```

**EDIT**
I must have gotten it from here:
[Jquery datepicker: validate date mm/dd/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715626/jquery-datepicker-validate-date-mm-dd-yyyy)

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to use JS `Date` to validate your date String.

```
var myDate = new Date(userInputString);

if (myDate == "Invalid Date"){
 // user input is invalid
}
```

Also note that `(myDate === "Invalid Date")` returns false even for invalid dates. Using == works fine however the correct way to check is `(isNaN( d.getTime()))`